# Display multi-line notification using notify-send in python

Tags: python, linux, notifications

I have weather(json) data from api. I want to display only a part of it which I put in a dictionary:

```
vals = {
'temperature': 34.41, 
'summary': 'Clear', 
'ozone': 249.95, 
'humidity': 0.32, 
'precipType': 'rain', 
'pressure': 1010.05, 
'dewPoint': 15.31, 
'time': 1456393033, 
'windSpeed': 2.5, 
'apparentTemperature': 34.23, 
'icon': 'clear-day', 
'windBearing': 96, 
'precipProbability': 0.01, 
'cloudCover': 0.17, 
'precipIntensity': 0.0203
}
```

I use this code to display the notification in the format of 'key: value'. Code follows:

```
for i in sorted(vals.keys()):

    if i == 'time':
        vals[i] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(vals[i])) #unix timestamp to readble format

    if i == 'summary':
        continue #Put it in the notif's title not body
    msg = msg + str(i).strip() + ':\ ' +str(vals[i]).strip() + '\n'

msg = 'notify-send -u critical ' + vals['summary'] + ' ' + msg
os.system(msg)
```

**The out displays a notification with the title(in this case, the summary- 'Clear') and the first key:value pair i.e. apparentTemperature: 34.23 and then the terminal shows the following error:**

```
sh: 2: cloudCover: 0.17: not found
sh: 3: dewPoint: 15.31: not found
sh: 4: humidity: 0.32: not found
sh: 5: icon: clear-day: not found
sh: 6: ozone: 249.95: not found
sh: 7: precipIntensity: 0.0203: not found
sh: 8: precipProbability: 0.01: not found
sh: 9: precipType: rain: not found
sh: 10: pressure: 1010.05: not found
sh: 11: temperature: 34.41: not found
sh: 12: time: 2016-02-25: not found
sh: 13: windBearing: 96: not found
sh: 14: windSpeed: 2.5: not found
```

What is the error and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 3):

The error is in `msg = 'notify-send -u critical ' + vals['summary'] + ' ' + msg`. Your `sh` thinks that arguments `vals['summary']` and `msg` are commands to execute by `sh`. It happens because of spaces in the output of your `msg` (I`m not telling you about confusion related to same names of your `msg`-variables).

You can avoid it using quotes (`\"`) in your output data. So `msg` can looks like

```
msg = 'notify-send -u critical \"%s %s\"' %% (vals['summary'], msg)
```

or

```
msg = 'notify-send -u critical ' + '\"' + vals['summary'] + ' ' + msg + '\"'
```

**UPD**
I don`t understand the main question before, so:

There are some troubles using multiline `notify-send` in scripts. The easiest way, I think, is to use `echo -e` in your script, for example:

```
notify-send "Title" "$(echo -e "This is the first line.\nAnd this is the second.")"
```

You can try to use this thought in your script, but you have to do some tricks with quotes and control characters.

Comment: I found the solution. It's just better to wrap all the body inside quotes i.e. ' {body} '.

Comment: @user2559578 Your comment should have been the accepted answer for this question :-) Do you want to add it?

Comment: Just small note!!!! It shows multi line if you hover your mouse on top of the notification!!